# Spring Boot Thin Jar with Custom parent POM

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, jar

I have been trying to use Spring Boot thin jar, on local it worked very well, JAR size was very small, but when i deployed the service JAR to the remote server, it didn't work. I read in a article that if you want to make it work, then POM must inherit Spring Boot Parent and i am using Custom parent pom, on remote server it says POM(parent pom) was not found. Thin Jar and Maven Boot configurations as below

```
   <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-layout</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.25.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

This POM inherits parent as following

```
 <parent>
    <artifactId>delivery-drivers</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.delivery</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>drivers-service</artifactId>
```

Parent inherits from Spring Boot Parent as following

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<groupId>com.delivery</groupId>
<artifactId>delivery-drivers</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modules>
    <module>drivers-api</module>
    <module>drivers-service</module>
</modules>
```

following is the server error

```
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.delivery:drivers-service:[unknown-version]: Could not find artifact com.delivery:delivery-drivers:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT in spring-snapshots (https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot) @ line 5, column 13
```

for project com.farsh:drivers-service:[unknown-version]

Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: Looks like you are missing a repository tag to obtain the dependencies from your local repo.

Comment: where is that added? could you please share some example?

Comment: The maven documentation about what the `<repositories>` tag is and does is pretty clear.

Comment: ok as if i understood, you are referring to add it to settings.xml, documentation says that there is no need to add repositories for local

Comment: No in your pom.xml. If you have dependencies from your own repository (which you should install) the `pom.xml` or `settings.xml` needs a link to it. I mean your local maven repository. Not your .m2 directory. The server doesn't have your .m2 directory and thus will try to download those files, which come from your local artifact server and not maven central or the spring repositories. (Like your parent `pom.xml`. ).